# Buick LeSabre '97 - 'Security' indicator light goes on... why and how to fix?

Tags: indicators

This is my in-law's car. They live in Los Angeles.

Two days ago when they started up the car,  the 'security' indicator light went on when they turned the key to start the car.

The engine would not start...we would just see the indicator light. I thought that perhaps     the steering wheel was in a position that locked the ignition. We played with the steering wheel and eventually the indicator light went off and the engine started.

The next day it happened again but the steering wheel trick didn't work. My in-law thinks the issue just timed out.

What could be causing this? How can this be fixed?

Comment: it could be the key, does the key have a resistor in it? If it doesn't i'd suspect a problem with the passlock sensor.

Comment: Interesting. The key does have a little plastic/metal bump along the shaft of the key. Maybe that bit needs to be fixed...

Comment: You'd need a scan tool to be sure, but if you have another key give it a try. Generally you need to replace the key if that resister fails. Try ohming the resister on the key. Also shine a light in the key cylinder there should be some contacts in there if they look too spread out or they aren't silver in color you may need to replace the sensor.